# func collectionView is called before dataTask() method completes

Tags: swift

I'm calling my webservice to return JSON data, which will then be used to populate cells in a UICollectionView. In order to determine the number of cells, I count the number of items returned in the JSON array. However, the problem is that my collectionView() function is called before my dataTask() function finishes (my guess is that dataTask() is asynchronous), which in turn gives me an error detailing that I'm accessing a nil value (jsonCount variable in TestController.swift). I've tried playing around with various completionHandlers and return values, but I can't get it to work. Could you guys please help point me in the right direction?

Your help / input is very much appreciated.

HomeModel.swift

```
class func getPostings(completionHandler: @escaping (_: Any) -> ()) {
        let url: URL = URL(string: "url")!
        let request: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {data, 
                   response, error in
                guard error == nil else {
                print(error!)
                completionHandler("Failed")
                return
                }
        let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
        let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

        if statusCode == 200 {
            let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [[String: Any]]
            completionHandler(json!)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

TestController.swift

```
var jsonCount: Int?
var jsonData: [[String: Any]]?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    HomeModel.getPostings(completionHandler: {(response: Any) -> Void in
        guard response as? String != "Failed" else {
            //Code to send a pop-up alert to the user
            return
        }
        self.jsonData = response as? [[String: Any]]
        self.jsonCount = (self.jsonData?.count)!
    })
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return jsonCount
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CollectionView` or `TableView` by default reload on `ViewDidLoad` method. But when you download something from server then just finishing download task update UI on Main Thread.

```
HomeModel.getPostings(completionHandler: {(response: Any) -> Void in
        guard response as? String != "Failed" else {
            //Code to send a pop-up alert to the user
            return
        }
        self.jsonData = response as? [[String: Any]]
        self.jsonCount = (self.jsonData?.count)!
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // Update UI on Main Thread
            collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    })
```

Comment: That worked, thank you so much!! Really appreciate it!